# How to match a long with Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I know i can match numbers with `Pattern.compile("\\d*");`

But it doesn't handle the long min/max values.

For performence issues related to exceptions i do not want to try to parse the long unless it is really a long.

```
if ( LONG_PATTERN.matcher(timestampStr).matches() ) {
    long timeStamp = Long.parseLong(timestampStr);
    return new Date(timeStamp);
} else {
    LOGGER.error("Can't convert " + timestampStr + " to a Date because it is not a timestamp! -> ");
    return null;
}
```

I mean i do not want any try/catch block and i do not want to get exceptions raised for a long like "564654954654464654654567879865132154778" which is out of the size of a regular Java long.

Does someone has a pattern to handle this kind of need for the primitive java types?
Does the JDK provide something to handle it automatically?
Is there a fail-safe parsing mecanism in Java?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** Please assume that the "bad long string" is not an exceptionnal case. 
I'm not asking for a benchmark, i'm here for a regex representing a long and nothing more. 
I'm aware of the additionnal time required by the regex check, but at least my long parsing will always be constant and never be dependent of the % of "bad long strings"

I can't find the link again but there is a nice parsing benchmark on StackOverflow which clearly shows that reusing the sams compiled regex is really fast, a LOT faster than throwing an exception, thus only a small threshold of exceptions whould make the system slower than with the additionnal regex check.

Comment: Note that `"\\d*"` matches empty strings as well.

Comment: Possibly [your question have already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563608/check-whether-a-string-is-parsable-into-long-without-try-catch). In my opinion, exceptions will be faster than regular expressions.

Comment: @Sorrow: Good catch on the earlier question. Re exceptions vs. regular expressions: What makes you think that? Throwing exceptions is not a quick process. Once compiled, regular expressions are quite quick.

Comment: As stated in my answer, it all depends on how often the exceptional case happens. With pattern matching you do the extra work _all the time_, with exceptions, the extra work is only done whenever the exception is raised.

Comment: @Sorrow, a precompiled pattern will outperform an exception that needs to be caught. But a (string) number that will fit in a `long` would be faster to check when `Long.parseLong(...)` does not throw an exception.

Comment: I agree with @gexicide here - it all depends on how often the exceptions are caught, as the regexps are checked always, no matter what. It seems to me that combining what T.J. Crowder answered (`-?\\d{1,19}`) with exception catching should be pretty much optimal, then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The minimum avlue of a `long` is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808`, and the maximum value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. So, a maximum of 19 digits. So, `\d{1,19}` should get you there, perhaps with an optional `-`, and with `^` and `$` to match the ends of the string.

So *roughly*:

```
Pattern LONG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d{1,19}$");
```

...or something along those lines, and assuming you don't allow commas (or have already removed them).

As gexicide points out in the comments, the above allows a small (in comparison) range of invalid values, such as `9,999,999,999,999,999,999`. You can get more complex with your regex, or just accept that the above will weed out the vast majority of invalid numbers and so you reduce the number of parsing exceptions you get.

Comment: not true, your pattern allows the number 9,999,999,999,999,999,999 which is NOT in the long range

Comment: @gexicide: True, some tuning might be required. It would at least vastly *reduce* the number of exceptions.

Comment: of course, but I guess OP wants a correct solution. But I agree, the pattern already filters most bad cases.

Comment: thanks, this is what i was also thinking of -> limiting the number of digits

Comment: can you explain the "-" please i don't find this in the pattern javadoc

Comment: @SebastienLorber: The `-` is a literal `-` (to allow for negative numbers), which is why you didn't find it in the javadoc. :-) The `?` after it means "zero or one time" (which is in the javadoc). E.g., `?` is a shortcut for `{0,1}`.

Comment: Oooh thanks i'm dumb ^^ but actually i just want positive values so i did not think of - as the long sign

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression should do what you need:

`^(-9223372036854775808|0)$|^((-?)((?!0)\d{1,18}|[1-8]\d{18}|9[0-1]\d{17}|92[0-1]\d{16}|922[0-2]\d{15}|9223[0-2]\d{14}|92233[0-6]\d{13}|922337[0-1]\d{12}|92233720[0-2]\d{10}|922337203[0-5]\d{9}|9223372036[0-7]\d{8}|92233720368[0-4]\d{7}|922337203685[0-3]\d{6}|9223372036854[0-6]\d{5}|92233720368547[0-6]\d{4}|922337203685477[0-4]\d{3}|9223372036854775[0-7]\d{2}|922337203685477580[0-7]))$`

But this regexp doesn't validate additional symbols like `+`, `L`, `_` and etc. And if you need to validate all possible Long values you need to upgrade this regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Simply catch the NumberFormatException, unless this case happens very often.

Another way would be to use a pattern which only allows long literals. Such pattern might be quite complex.

A third way would be to parse the number as BigInt first. Then you can compare it to Long.MAX_VALUE and Long.MIN_VALUE to check whether it is in the bounds of long. However, this might be costly as well.

*Also note:
Parsing the long is quite fast, it is a very optimized method (that, for example, tries to parse two digits in one step). Applying pattern matching might be even more costly than performing the parsing. The only thing which is slow about the parsing is throwing the NumberFormatException. Thus, simply catching the exception is the best way to go if the exceptional case does not happen too often*

Comment: The OP said: *"For performence issues related to exceptions i do not want to try to parse the long unless it is really a long"*

Comment: the idea is to get a constant execution time for the method instead of an execution time related to the presence of wrong long values. As far as i know, i've read a benchmark on SO and regexs, when not recompiled everytime, are pretty fast

Comment: I'm reading the [source code of `parseLong`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.parseLong%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29), however i'm not finding any evidence of parsing two-by-two digits.