# Spring boot rest single path variable which takes different type of values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-restcontroller, spring-repositories

Spring boot rest how to provide an end point which has one path variable which takes different types of values

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/user/{idOrName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User findUser(@PathVariable String idOrName) {
  this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(idOrName, idOrName);
}

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
  User findByIdOrName(Long id, String name);
}

@Data
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {
  private Long Id;
  private String name;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**
As you can see from the User model, Id is typeof `Long` and Name is typeof `String`. Now I need to implement single end point which offers facility to search user by id or name.

How can I implement rest end point which is having one path variable which either accept id or name which are of different type?

My problem is Not sure how to define `@PathVariable` when user sends either `String` or `Long`. Is it even possible to do? or should I make `@PathVariable` as `String` and parse `Long`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of {id:.+} in a Spring MVC requestmapping handler method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527321/what-is-the-meaning-of-id-in-a-spring-mvc-requestmapping-handler-method) . I found this possible duplicate, but you could search google for "Spring @PathVariable regular expression matching".

Comment: @GPI my question is different. I am wondering how findByIdOrName works in spring data when Id is Long and Name is String. How can I even pass parameters to this method?

Comment: I'm suggesting you try mapping 2 controler methods, one with a @RequestMapping like `/user/{id:\d+}`validating that the input is only made of digits, and another one validating that there is at least a non digit, e.g. `@RequestMapping("/user/{id:.*\D.*}")`. This way 2 request mappings, two methods, but a single HTTP route exists.

Comment: There are couple of answers in this thread to address your question. If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: @Dorado none of the answer talks about how findByIdOrName works? So I am waiting. findByIdOrName takes 2 parametes not one. Just wondering whether findByIdOrName is possible or not when Id and Name are different types (Eg: Long and String)

Comment: @PratapA.K You should take some time to read the documentation at Spring as it provides detailed definition and examples about `@PathVariable` more than I could assemble in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. You can't mix different types into a single @PathVariable as Spring says so on their documentation.

According to [Spring IO](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) documentation about `@PathVariable`:

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc. Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type or throws a TypeMismatchException if it fails to do so.

Note the documentation outlines ***A @PathVariable argument*** as singular object type that is not interchangeable into different types.

In addition, it's perfectly normal to have exception handling as answered in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563675/9620647) that trying to determine Long from String without `try/catch` isn't even worth the work and degrades performance.

You could use a single `@PathVariable` and have `try/catch` block to capture `NumberFormatException` or simply a regular expression.

**Method 1: Exception Handling**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{identifier}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User findUser(@PathVariable("identifier") String identifier) {
    try {
        Long long_identifier = Long.parseLong(identifier);
        this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(long_identifier);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //We know it's a plain string by now.
        this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(identifier);
    }
}
```

**Method 2: Regular Expression**

*Note: if value is not found, the query should simply return empty result.*

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{identifier}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User findUser(@PathVariable("identifier") String identifier) {
    //Check for digits only
    String regexpr = "\\d+";
    this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(
        identifier.matches(regexpr)
        ? Long.parseLong(identifier)
        : identifier
    );
}
```

**Method 3: Request Mappings with Regular Expression**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{identifier:[A-Za-z]+}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User findUserByString(@PathVariable("identifier") String identifier) {
    this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(identifier);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/user/{identifier:[0-9]+}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public User findUserByLong(@PathVariable("identifier") Long identifier) {
    this.userRepository.findByIdOrName(identifier);
}
```

Comment: I find the argument about the "normality" of exception handling debatable. If you "expect" a Long, then try/catch/exception makes sense because a string would be an "unexpected" situation. Here the question states that is is *expected* that the input might be a non-number. If the code is expected to throw, then, we are using exceptions as control flow (if/else), and that is not generally a pattern we follow. As I say, debatable. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: @GPI Your comment is debatable. Exception is not anti-pattern unless the application *entirely* depend on exceptions for control flow. Most web application, in fact, are prone to exception of some kind, and I have not seen any large-scale web application that produces no exception at all. I think Method 3 could be a good approach to handle requests to a *single* URL and ease with maintenance if both methods are implemented in same controller.

Comment: In my view, option 3 is the best, although I would carrefully craft the "non number" regular expression differently (eg `.*\D.*` or the like), or check if Spring actually falls back if I provide none at all. I'm not trying to argue about exceptions, I agree there is a grey area. I lean on the side of "they are exception all over the place (timeouts, SQL constraints, input validation, ....), but I prefer to have those for things that should not happen, and have if/else control the business logic". Not to mention Exception are heavy objects (stack trace allocation !).

Answer (score 0):

Given this is a search, another reasonable approach is to use query parameters:

```
/users?name=jdoe
```

or

```
/users?id=123
```

And use multiple @QueryParameter instead of @PathParameter.

And consider creating aliases which do use @PathParamter such as:

```
/users/name/{name}
/users/id/{id}
```

Clients could use the query parameters approach or the alias, whichever is easier. `findUser()`can simply delegate to `findById()` or `findByName()` depending on which query parameter was provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Calling findById or findByName depending variable type is fine, was wondering how does findByIdOrName() works when Id and Name are of different types